# locust 'Events' object has no attribute 'request_success'

Tags: locust

I am trying the below grpc locust script but it gives the following error :

> events.request_success.fire(request_type="grpc", ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'Events' object has no attribute 'request_success'

Script

```
import sys
import grpc
import inspect
import time
import gevent

# Libs
from locust.contrib.fasthttp import FastHttpUser
from locust import task, events, constant
from locust import events as ev

from locust.runners import STATE_STOPPING, STATE_STOPPED, STATE_CLEANUP, WorkerRunner



from **** import PublicAPIStub

import ****.v1.public_api_pb2 as dtos
import domain.v1.dto_pb2 as domain
import domain.v1.geo_pb2 as geo



def stopwatch(func):
    """To be updated"""

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """To be updated"""
        # get task's function name
        previous_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        _, _, task_name, _, _ = inspect.getframeinfo(previous_frame)

        start = time.time()
        result = None
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            total = int((time.time() - start) * 1000)
            ev.request_failure.fire(request_type="grpc",
                                        name=task_name,
                                        response_time=total,
                                        response_length=0,
                                        exception=e)
        else:
            total = int((time.time() - start) * 1000)
            ev.request_success.fire(request_type="grpc",
                                        name=task_name,
                                        response_time=total,
                                        response_length=0)
        return result

    return wrapper

class GRPCMyLocust(FastHttpUser):
    host = 'http://*********:443'
    wait_time = constant(0)

    def on_start(self):
        """ on_start is called when a Locust start before any task is scheduled """
        pass

    def on_stop(self):
        """ on_stop is called when the TaskSet is stopping """
        pass

    @task
    @stopwatch
    def grpc_client_task(self):
        """To be updated"""
        try:
            ssl_metadata = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()
            with grpc.secure_channel('laas-zz-lt.usehurrier.com:443', ssl_metadata) as channel:
                input_data = dtos.Request(type='test')
                stub = PublicAPIStub(channel)
                stub.ListAvailableVendors(input_data)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            sys.exit(0)

# Stopping the locust if a threshold (in this case the fail ratio) is exceeded
def checker(environment):
    while not environment.runner.state in [STATE_STOPPING, STATE_STOPPED, STATE_CLEANUP]:
        time.sleep(1)
        if environment.runner.stats.total.fail_ratio > 0.4:
            print(f"fail ratio was {environment.runner.stats.total.fail_ratio}, quitting")
            environment.runner.quit()
            return


@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **_kwargs):
    if not isinstance(environment.runner, WorkerRunner):
        gevent.spawn(checker, environment)
```

Any idea what might be the problem with the script?

Note: I am receiving a response from the server so the connection works fine.

locust --version: locust 2.15.1 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/locust (python 3.11.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locust 1.5 deprecated `request_success` and `request_failure` in favor of a unified `request` event.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/changelog.html#id47

2.15 removed the deprecated ones.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/changelog.html#id2

Here's the doc for `request` event.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.request

So for you, it'd be something like:

```
ev.request.fire(request_type="grpc",
                name=task_name,
                response_time=total,
                response_length=0,
                exception=e)
```

and

```
ev.request.fire(request_type="grpc",
                name=task_name,
                response_time=total,
                response_length=0)
```